# Howto ban my ip in google analytic account

Tags: google-analytics

i have Google analytic   account ,

I want to ban my ip in google analatic account ,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a static IP you can exclude it from Analytics quite easy by defining a filter containing your IP within Analytics.

If your ISP assigns you a dynamic IP the process gets slightly more complicated: You have to store a special cookie on all your PCs / browsers that will cause Analytics to disregard your visits to your own site. Setting this cookie can be done by creating an additional HTML page within your site; everyone who visits that page will receive the cookie and will therefore not be tracked by Analytics when surfing your website (therefore you might want to password protect that page or remove it after you created the cookie on your own computers).

Both methods are described on [Google's Analytics support pages](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55481). 
Note that both approaches will only exclude your IP from all future data captured by Analytics.